# Need help with Double Definite Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help in solving this double integral:

$$\int\limits^2_{-2}\;\;\int\limits^\sqrt{4-x^2}_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}{(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}dy\,dx$$

Maybe introducing polar coordinates might help?

Comment: I think you'll need polar coordinates here.

Comment: @John Yes, that's what I meant when I said introduce an r.

Comment: And ... What did you get when you tried with polar coordinates?

Comment: Just go to polar coordinates. You are integrating over a circle of radius 2 centered at the origin so it's ptetty easy

Comment: @Antoine Nevermind, I was thinking of something different. How would you do this using polar coordinates?

Comment: Like Dr. MV did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-2}^{2}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}dy\,dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2r^5\,rdr\,d\theta=\frac{256}{7}\pi$$

after transforming to polar coordinates with

$$x=r\cos \theta\\\\
y=r\sin \theta$$

and the Jacobian equal to $r$ so that $dx\,dy\to r\,dr\,d\theta$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by Jacobian equal to the r?

Comment: He just means $dxdy=rdrd\theta$. In general, the Jacobian of a transformation is the determinant of the matrix of partial derivatives, which tells you how to transform $dxdy$ into different coordinates.

Comment: Can you show the solving of the double integral, if you don't mind?

Comment: @sofia To carry out the inner integral in Cartesian form is very tedious.  Suffice to say that this can be done a number of ways.  One way is to use repeated integration by parts starting with $u=(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}$, $v=y$ in the first part and proceeding patiently through.

Answer (score 0):

You can express $x^2 + y^2$ in polar coordinates using:

$x = rcos\theta, \ y = rsin\theta$

$$x^2 + y^2 = r^2cos^2\theta + r^2sin^2\theta = r^2$$
$$(x^2 + y^2)^{\frac{5}{2}} = (r^2)^\frac{5}{2} = r^5$$

Essentially, the region is a circle with radius 2 and the angle goes from $0$ to $2\pi$

$$\frac{\partial (x, y)}{\partial (r, \theta)} = r$$
The integral now becomes:

$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^2 r^5.r \ dr\ d\theta$$

$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{r^7}{7} d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{128}{7}d\theta$$

$$\left(\frac{128}{7}\theta\right)_0^{2\pi}$$

$$ \frac{256}{7}\pi$$

In general, you can transform an integral over a region into another integral over a second region using:

$$ \int \int_D f(x, y)\ dx \ dy =\int \int_{\Delta} f(g_1(u, v), g_2(u, v))\left|\frac{\partial (x, y)}{\partial (u, v)}\right| \  du\  dv  $$